# setSinkId API not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The HTMLMediaElement.setSinkId() allows the app defining which audio output device to use for a given HTML audio/video element. This is currently implemented in the Chrome browser family. But it doesn't work if I call it from a Google Chrome Extension app. The audio will always play out via the OS's default selected device

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) the question is probably unanswerable. It may be also a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the output device by using a content script with the following code:

```
let videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

const constraints = {
  audio: true
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(stream) {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  })
  .then(function(deviceInfo) {
    // Use this to find the target device.
    console.log(deviceInfo);

    for (let device of deviceInfo) {
      if (device.label === AUDIO_DEVICE_LABEL) {
        return videoElement[0].setSinkId(device.deviceId);
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

The call to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)` should trigger a popup requesting permission to use your microphone (unfortunately it would appear that this is necessary regardless of whether you use the microphone or not).

Once permission has been granted, the device should update properly.